# Immutable.js - TypeError: get(...).toJS is not a function

Tags: react-redux, immutable.js

struggling on ImmutableJS... getting error:

> TypeError: this.props.dataTable.get(...).toJS is not a function

relating to this line:

```
let tbodyRows = this.props.dataTable.get('data').toJS();
```

When I do console.log `this.props.dataTable.get('data')` I get Array[1] and this array contains a single object of data (which is what I would expect).

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `.toJS()`, `this.props.dataTable.get('data')` should be returning a `List` (in this case) not an `Array`.